# Asus Zenfone 6 doesn't see SIM cards, keeps booting itself. How to troubleshoot the issue?

Tags: sim-card, troubleshooting

I have a problem with Asus Zenfone 6 device, which worked well on stock firmware with minimal amount of additional installs for about a year. This is a dual SIM phone and it has both SIM card slots used.

At some point the device stopped "seeing" both SIM cards, and started self-booting (gracefully, with reboot notice) every 2-3 minutes.

A sequence of factory resets and firmware updates did not solve SIM card problem. Other than this, the phone worked well: recovery, installed new firmware, WiFi etc. The situation got better with last firmware update coming with Android 5: the phone simply does not see SIM cards now, without rebooting itself any longer.

- While I tend to think it is simply a hardware problem, how do I go about troubleshooting the problem from as a developer?
- I have `adb` connection, I can grab logs (`adb logcat`, `adb bugreport`) which contain lots of data, I can connect via shell. It is a lot of data, what do I check there specifically?
- Or, how do I check hardware configuration to detect details of anomalies (missing SIM related devices or configurations), or hardware related logs?

Answer (score -1):

try adding a small piece of tissue on the top of the sim card slot, i have the same problem and it seems like the slot is loosen up, so you will need something to keep the slot pushed down , for example : paper, tissue, etc. but , tissue works the best.